I want to check if the cell is empty, if not I want to display another value from another cell
I want to check if the cell is empty, if not I want to display another value from another cell.
Here is my existing formula but doesn't work:
=IF(ISBLANK(DTR2024_26days!B9:E9), DTR2024_26days!H9:I9, DTR2024_26days!B9:E9)


ISBLANK() only works if the cell is truely blank, if there's a formula inside it that returns "", then ISBLANK will not trigger a TRUE. Try something like DTR2024_26days!B9:E9<>"" instead of ISBLANK; apart from that, there's very little info in your question to actually help out.

ISBLANK function can only evaluate single cells, but you are trying to check a range (B9:E9). Instead of using ISBLANK for a range, you should use a different approach, such as checking if the sum of the range is 0 (for numbers), or using the COUNTA function to check if any of the cells in the range are not blank (for mixed or text data).

You need to evaluate each cell of the range. If the cells are really empty, nothing is there, this should work:
=IF(COUNTA(DTR2024_26days!B9:E9) = 0, DTR2024_26days!H9:I9, DTR2024_26days!B9:E9)

On the other hand if you are checking if the sum of values in the range is 0, you should change it to:
=IF(SUM(DTR2024_26days!B9:E9) = 0, DTR2024_26days!H9:I9, DTR2024_26days!B9:E9)


I guess OP don't want to use the integral condition. DTR2024_26days!B9:E9<>"" looks more reasonable.
